# SQL SUM function with added

Tags: sql

total novice here with SQL SUM function question. So, SUM function itself works as I expected it to:

```
select ID, sum(amount) 
from table1
group by ID
```

There are several records for each ID and my goal is to summarize each ID on one row where the next column would give me the summarized amount of column AMOUNT.

This works fine, however I also need to filter out based on certain criteria in the summarized amount field. I.e. only look for results where the summarized amount is either bigger, smaller or between certain number.

This is the part I'm struggling with, as I can't seem to use column AMOUNT, as this messes up summarizing results.

Column name for summarized results is shown as "00002", however using this in the between or > / < clause does not work either. Tried this:

```
select ID, sum(amount)
from table1
where 00002 > 1000
group by ID
```

No error message, just blank result, however plenty of summarized results with values over 1000.

Unfortunately not sure on the engine the database runs on, however it should be some IBM-based product.

Comment: Use the `having` clause for that instead of `where`

Comment: use alias as column names. And as mentioned use having to use aggregated column operations. `select ID, sum(amount) as sum_amount from table1 group by ID having sum(amount) = 'some value'`

Comment: 2 is never > 1000...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause will filter individual rows that don't match the condition before aggregating them.

If you want to do post aggregation filtering you need to use the `HAVING` Clause.

`HAVING` will apply the filter to the results after being grouped.

```
select ID, sum(amount)
from table1
group by ID
having sum(amount) > 1000
```